# Specify different border-radius values for each corner with NativeScript

Tags: ios, css, hybrid-mobile-app, nativescript

Is it possible to specify different border-radius values for each corner with `NativeScript` as I can with CSS in browsers? (Or is there any workarounds?)
I tried code like below on my iOS emulator, but it didn't make any change.

```
border-radius: 20 0 0 20;
```

using this;

- NativeScript CLI: 2.0.0
- tns-core-modules: 2.0.1
- tns ios Runtime: 2.0.0

I'll appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `NativeScript` is not possible to specify border radius in this way. Possible decision is given in this `github` issue [using clip path](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/2152)